# USB audio interfaces and unusual guitar output

Tags: xlr, phantom

I have a nylon crossover guitar, with the output consisting of a male XLR connector instead of the usual jack socket. The instrument does not require an internal battery as it uses the +48v phantom power provided by the cable. Unfortunately I have no way to know the characteristics of the electronics contained in the guitar because the instrument was originally not amplified and I no longer have any contacts with the engineer who designed the amplification system.

The connection to the amplifier does not give particular problems and the sound seems good. The problems arise instead when I use most USB audio interfaces to record guitar on the computer: some seem to work (in the sense that the quality is acceptable, but not excellent); others give unacceptable results (low level, muffled sound, etc.). The idea I got is that the output signal from my guitar is too high for the XLR ports of conventional audio interfaces, which are instead designed to receive microphone-level signals (this hypothesis has been confirmed by the dramatic improvement obtained by connecting a -15dB attenuator between the guitar output and the XLR MIC input of the sound card). I therefore ask you the following two questions:

1. is there an audio interface on the market that provides phantom power on a line input (TRS jack)?

Or as an alternative:

2. is there an audio interface on the market that accepts line level signals on a phantom-powered XLR input port?

I did some research on the web, but couldn't find anything. Thanks to anyone who will answer me.

Comment: What do you mean by “The connection to the amplifier… and the sound seems good” ? Are you talking about a guitar amp?

Comment: Exactly. The MIC input of my guitar amp seems to work. The problem occurs only with USB audio interfaces. Perhaps the technical specifications of the amp's XLR MIC inputs are different. I don't know. However, my question is specifically about USB audio interfaces. I only mentioned the amplifier because it seems strange that it doesn't have the same problem.

Comment: Ok I thought you were interested in why you were having the problem

Comment: I think the designer used the XLR type connection just to take advantage of phantom power, overlooking the fact that the audio signal is too high for a MIKE input. I would only appreciate the answer to at least one of the two questions I asked in my first post :-)

Comment: If they don't sell one, then you're usually doing something wrong. I think you're asking the wrong question, you should be asking about retrofitted internal mic/sensors and preamps and how to power them properly. I'm no guitar player, so I'm not sure about preamps and DIs and stuff. I'd just take it off and have a look-see what's going on. Maybe it has a manufacture name on it you can google. If you don't tackle the root problem, I doubt you'll ever get a clean signal to record.

Comment: I'm closing this - it's really just asking for a recommendation for a product that is only needed for this particular device, which has not been built using existing standards. So you will need to use an interface, or change the electronics, or buy a new guitar.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not any reason to sell something like that, however pro mixing consoles can do that with an XLR +48V line input.

in my opinion the issue is probably not that the signal is line level. but if you look at the technical specs for most interfaces they will accept higher than +4dBu on the mic inputs.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I've always used a single audio interface with no additional equipment. It seems rather uncomfortable and economically disadvantageous to me to buy a mixer just to record my tracks on the computer. So I was looking for a USB audio interface with the features described above. Thank you for your kind reply.

Comment: @Ronnie88 yes of course it would be cheaper to buy a new guitar or microphone.